# Creating Carousel with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I created a two-row carousel (HTML code and screenshot below).

1. How to make them work with `JQuery` or `Javascript` -> when I click on the "right" or "left" arrow, to move both rows at the same time, one image at the time?
2. How to make the first image from the right in the first row to be in focus?

   ```
       <div class="arrows-row2">
         <div class="arrow-item next">
           <button onclick="changeSlide('next')">
             <img src="images/str_des_crna.png" alt="">
           </button>
         </div>
         <div class="arrow-item">
           <button onclick="changeSlide('previous')">
             <img src="images/str_left_crna.png" alt="">
           </button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider__right">
     <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, 
      consequatur.</p>
   </div>
   ```

[Image of the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPLpH.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, this should help you

```
$(function () {
    var slick = $('.your-class').slick({
        appendArrows: $('#arrows')
    });

    $('.slick-next').on('click', function () {
        slick.slickNext();
    });
    $('.slick-prev').on('click', function () {
        slick.slickPrev();
    }); });
```

**Demo** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Micio/cv9zpypr/377/)

Comment: Tnx for helping. The problem with your version is it shows just one image per row although you have 3 images in each row. I have 9 images in each row. 
All images must be shown in each row and then move to the left or right by one image, when I click on next or prev arrow.
For example, in your code, there would be 3 images in a first row and 3 in a second row. When clicking next or prev it would move by one image to the right or left. I hope you understand what I mean